# Is this user "votetoclose" a new way to cast a close vote?

Tags: discussion, user-accounts

I was fascinated by this new user [votetoclose](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/70619/votetoclose). Is this a new way to cast close votes on The Workplace, or just another user?

Comment: Thank you for pointing this user out; the tone of their "answer" is not acceptable and it looks like the community is dealing with it.

Answer (score 10):

It's just another user. You can choose almost any name you like, as long as it isn't offensive.

It looks like it was someone who created an account for the purpose of voting to close a question, not really understanding how the site works.

Answer (score 10):

As of now, there are no special "vote to close" accounts, but even if StackExchange introduces one in future, you can be sure the user name will be suffixed with the diamond (♦) character. Moreover, its purpose will be clearly described on the profile.

Ordinary accounts are not allowed to use the ♦ character in the user name to prevent users from misleading others or misrepresenting the site. It is attached only to moderator accounts, SE employee accounts and the special SE-administered bot account [Community ♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community).

If you come across more such <s>troll</s> fascinating accounts ("vote to delete", "downvote this answer", "ban this moderator", etc.), just note the missing diamond. Such user accounts are invariably created for ["interesting" activity](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/91682/3192), which you should also downvote and flag to moderators.